# Pygame error: display surface quit: Why?

Tags: python, pygame

Can anyone tell me why my app quits with:

> pygame error: display Surface quit.

Comment: Post the entire traceback, and at the very least the code for the function where the exception is raised.

Comment: Really, without a [mcve], this question should be closed. However, it's got some valuable answers worth keeping around.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar problem and discovered that Surface objects don't like to be deepcopied. When I used copy.deepcopy() on such object and then accessed the copy, I got that strange error message (without calling pygame.quit()). Maybe you experience similar behavior?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem in a very simple piece of code:

```
    import sys, pygame
    pygame.init()

    size = width, height = 640, 480
    speed = [2, 2]
    black = 0, 0, 0

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    ball = pygame.image.load("Golfball.png")
    ballrect = ball.get_rect()
    while 1:
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

        ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
        if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
            speed[0] = -speed[0]
        if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(5)
```

Error message was:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "bounce.py", line 22, in <module>
        screen.fill(black)
    pygame.error: display Surface quit
```

So I put

```
    import pdb
```

at the top after

```
    pygame.init()
```

and used

```
    pdb.set_trace()
```

*after* the line with

```
    pygame.quit()
```

Now I ran the program, clicked to close the window and was actually a bit surprised to see that I fell into the debugger (after all, I expected the quit to completely take me out immediately). So I concluded that the *quit* doesn't actually stop everything at that point. Looked like the program was continuing beyond the quit, was reaching

```
    screen.fill(black)
```

and this was causing the problem.
So I added

```
    break
```

after the

```
    pygame.quit()
```

and all works happily now.

[ Added later: It occurs to me now that

```
    pygame.quit()
```

is quitting the *module*, and not the *program that is running*, so you need the *break* to get out of this simple program. ]

Just for the record, this means the good version is

```
    import sys, pygame
    pygame.init()

    size = width, height = 640, 480
    speed = [2, 2]
    black = 0, 0, 0

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    ball = pygame.image.load("Golfball.png")
    ballrect = ball.get_rect()
    while 1:
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                break

        ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
        if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
            speed[0] = -speed[0]
        if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(5)
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace `if event.type == pygame.quit():` by `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure if you write `pygame.QUIT:` and not `pygame.quit():`
I know it sounds weird, but I had the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pygame, sys

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit() # quit the screen
        running = False
        sys.exit()
```

call sys.exit() after pygame.quit() to stop the program so you can not change the surface after you have quit pygame and not get the error

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem just right now and I have found a solution to it.

Because it seems like **pygame.quit()** will just quit the pygame module and not the entire program, use **sys.exit()** method on the following line.

After this:

```
pygame.quit()
```

Place this:

```
sys.exit()
```

Complete snippet:

```
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://archives.seul.org/pygame/users/Nov-2006/msg00236.html :

On Thu, 2006-11-30 at 21:27 -0300, Nicolas Bischof wrote:

> pygame.error: display Surface quit
>   what does that mean?, i can't fix it

This means a call was made to pygame.display.quit() or pygame.quit(). If
you try to do anything to the display surface after quit you will get
this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, but got it from another origin.

I had a class defined like this:

```
class PauseMenu(pygame.Surface)
```

i got the error when forgetting to initialize the pygame.Surface and trying to blit it, making pygame.screen crash and gave me this error.

so i just added this obviously

```
pygame.Surface.__init__(self, (width, height))
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem, and similar to Maciej Miąsik's answer mine had to do with copy.deepcopy()-ing an image.

I had:

```
import copy,pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

EMPTY_IMG= pygame.image.load('C:super/fancy/file/path/transparent.png')
held_image=copy.deepcopy(EMPTY_IMG)
my_rect=held_image.get_rect()
my_rect.center = (50,50)
screen.blit(held_image,my_rect)
```

And I got the same error.

I simply changed the copy.deepcopy(EMPTY_IMG) to just EMPTY_IMG.

```
import copy,pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

EMPTY_IMG= pygame.image.load('C:super/fancy/file/path/transparent.png')
held_image=EMPTY_IMG
my_rect=held_image.get_rect()
my_rect.center = (50,50)
screen.blit(held_image,my_rect)
```

Then it all worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just update the display in the infinite loop.

Type this:

pygame.display.update()